# Assign unique ids to elements with same class

Tags: jquery

I am creating a website in which I have two different buttons.

By using jQuery, I want to hide and show two elements. Both elements are the text. e.g by click on `buttonA`, `textA` should show and if `textB` was visible, it should hide. similarly by click on `buttonB`, `textB` should show and if `textA` was visible, it should hide. Initially both the text should be hidden but loaded on their positions.

Both the texts have same positioning on the layout. i have defined a class (.content is its name) which maintains all the styling for the text. Now the issue I am facing is that I have two div both with the class but I am unable to give two different ids to the texts.

```
.content {
  visibility:hidden;
  border-style: none;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: centre;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 40%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size:2.5em;
}
```

The problem is here how to assign some unique ids also to both texts

```
<div class="content">TextA goes here<br></div>
<div class="content">TextB goes here<br></div>
```

so when I use jquery

```
$("#ButtonA").click(function(){
  $("#TextA").show();$("#TextB").hide();
});

$("#ButtonB").click(function(){
  $("#TextB").show();$("#TextA").hide();
});
```

Though it might be lame question but I couldnt figure it out myself so had to ask.

Comment: Why can't you give them different IDs?

Comment: `$(".content").each(function(index, elem){ elem.id = "Text" + index; })`

Comment: Could you give them each a unique class and use that to hang on to?

Comment: Can this not be accomplished using a class of '.hidden' set to display: none, and toggleClass?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Can you explain why you can't use different ids for the elements?

```
<div class="content" id="TextA">TextA goes here<br></div>
<div class="content" id="TextB">TextB goes here<br></div>
```

Comment: "I am unable to give two different ids to the texts"

Comment: I got your answer. actually I have used your answer precisely. :)

Comment: What?! Is this your solution?! :S

Comment: Why did this get so many downvotes? Because it's too simple a solution? It solved the issue...

Comment: Because everyone else was thinking about a different question.

Comment: Poor man doesn't deserve the down votes but I'll leave it as it is cause its funny, -6 for the right answer

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to add id's, just get them with jQuery -

```
$("#ButtonA").click(function(){
    $('.content').eq(0).show();
    $('.content').eq(1).hide();
});

$("#ButtonB").click(function(){
    $('.content').eq(1).show();
    $('.content').eq(0).hide();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ButtonA").click(function(){
    $('.content').eq(0).show();
    $('.content').eq(1).hide();
});

$("#ButtonB").click(function(){
    $('.content').eq(1).show();
    $('.content').eq(0).hide();    
});​
```

-- ALSO CHANGE --

```
.content {
    border-style: none;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: centre;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 40%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size:2.5em;
    /* visibility: hidden; CHANGE THIS TO */
    display: none;
}​​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gEs66/1/

Comment: Is this not pretty much exactly what Jay Blanchard posted already?!

Comment: it is, however the css is needed in order for the javascript to work. I am just improving on the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I totally understand the question but I would take an approach like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/HdhKQ/

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="content">TextA goes here</div>
    <div class="button">TextA Button</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="content" style="display:none">TextB goes here</div>
    <div class="button">TextB Button</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.button { cursor:pointer; }

.content {
border-style: none;
display: block;
position: fixed;
text-align: centre;
z-index: 1;
margin-top: 40%;
margin-left: 25%;
margin-right: 25%;
background-color: transparent;
font-size:2.5em;
}​
```

JS
$(".button").click(function(){

```
// Hide all content element
$(".content").hide();

// Show the content for the related button
$(this).parent().children('.content').show();
```

});
​

Comment: No worries Maleeha, someone else did the downvote, I am looking for an explanation from them since this is a valid solution.